# ckeditor throwing error when manipulating the dom Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am managing users posts. Every user can comment a post. But when the post is 'solved', i want to hide the ckeditor that allows users to add comments.

I used this piece of code inside post detail component:

```
  <div *ngIf="!(ticket?.status === 'solved')">
    <app-response-add [res]="respon"></app-response-add>
  </div>
```

And this is the response-add component:

```
    <div class="card-body">
        <ck-editor [(ngModel)]="responseContent" class="editor" [config]="{ toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic' ] }"></ck-editor>
        <button data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" class="btn btn-sm btn-success mt-2" (click)="onAddResponse()">Ajouter</button>
    </div>
```

It throws this error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null

Ps: When i remove the ngIf form the app-response-add markup, everything works smoothly.